# Replacing row elements in a column based on row elements from another column in Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hi this is my first post in stack overflow so apologies if formatting is incorrect and if this has been asked before - i havent been able to find a solution.

Im trying to replace certain strings from a column based on certain criteria from another column. I have the following data frame:

```
> df
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   Group1         Group2          Group3               
   <chr>          <chr>           <chr>                
 1 MOBILES        MOBILES - CORE  IOT                  
 2 MOBILES        MOBILES - CORE  IOT_Vas                  
 3 MOBILES        MOBILES - CORE  IOT_Vas              
 4 Data & IP      Data & IP       IP WAN               
 5 Data & IP      Data & IP       Internet Solutions   
 6 Data & IP      Data & IP       Internet Solutions   
 7 MOBILES        IOT             M2M                  
 8 MOBILES        IOT             M2M                  
 9 MOBILES        IOT             M2M VAS              
10 MOBILES        IOT             M2M VAS              
11 Cloud Services Cloud Services  Professional Services
12 Cloud Services Cloud Services  Professional Services
13 Mobiles        MOBILES - CORE  MOBILES - CORE       
14 Mobiles        MOBILES - Voice MOBILES - Voice
```

What im trying to achieve is if "Group 3" contains the string IOT then the value in "Group 1" = IOT and if "Group 3" contains M2M then the value "Group 1" = M2M. Otherwise the values in Group 1 to remain the same.

Im relatively new to stack overflow and the R tidyverserse but ive been unable to find a solution to my problem. Ive tried str_replace and mutate_at but havent been able to figure out how to do this when im replacing based on 2 different elements.

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   Group1         Group2          Group3               
   <chr>          <chr>           <chr>                
 1 IOT            MOBILES - CORE  IOT                  
 2 IOT            MOBILES - CORE  IOT                  
 3 IOT            MOBILES - CORE  IOT_Vas              
 4 Data & IP      Data & IP       IP WAN               
 5 Data & IP      Data & IP       Internet Solutions   
 6 Data & IP      Data & IP       Internet Solutions   
 7 M2M            IOT             M2M                  
 8 M2M            IOT             M2M                  
 9 M2M            IOT             M2M VAS              
10 M2M            IOT             M2M VAS              
11 Cloud Services Cloud Services  Professional Services
12 Cloud Services Cloud Services  Professional Services
13 Mobiles        MOBILES - CORE  MOBILES - CORE       
14 Mobiles        MOBILES - Voice MOBILES - Voice
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with `tidyverse` -

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    Group1 = case_when(
      str_detect(Group3, "IOT") ~ "IOT",
      str_detect(Group3, "M2M") ~ "M2M",
      TRUE ~ Group1
    )
  )
```

You can also do this in base R using `ifelse` and `grepl` -

```
df$Group1 <- ifelse(grepl("IOT", df$Group3), "IOT",
                    ifelse(grepl("M2M", df$Group3), "M2M", df$Group1)
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your data frame here by creating `group1` that will be changed based on the values of `group3`. I created a for loop that changes `group1` to either "M2M" or "IOT" if either of those strings are detected within group3, but if neither string is found then the `group1` value remains unchanged.

```
df <- data.frame(group1 = c("TEST", "TEST", "TEST", "TEST", "TEST"),
                 group3 = c("M2M", "DATA AND IP", "IOT", "M2M VAS", "IOT MORETEXT"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# loop through rows in df
for  (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    # is the string "M2M" in group3?
    if (str_detect(df$group3[i], "M2M")) {
      # if so reassign group1 to M2M
      df$group1[i] <- "M2M"
    # use the same logic, but with the string "IOT"
    } else if (str_detect(df$group3[i], "IOT")) {
      df$group1[i] <- "IOT"
    } else {
      # otherwise keep group1 the same
      df$group1[i] <- df$group1[i]
    }
}
```

Hope that helps and I'm happy to answer any further questions or provide clarification!

Comment: `str_detect` is vectorized, so you don't need a loop