# Rename specific column elements based on elements in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

Apologies if this is a simple problem, I was really struggling to find a solution. There's this question here which is similar, but not quite the same and none of the solutions seemed to work for me: [Replacing row elements in a column based on row elements from another column in Tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032358/replacing-row-elements-in-a-column-based-on-row-elements-from-another-column-in)

I have a df as follows:

```
Loop <- c('0','1','','0','1','2','0','1','','0','1','2')
Condition <- c('base','base','base','AOMI1','AOMI1','AOMI1','control','control',
               'control','AOMI2','AOMI2','AOMI2')

df <- data.frame(Loop, Condition)

   Loop Condition
1     0      base
2     1      base
3            base
4     0     AOMI1
5     1     AOMI1
6     2     AOMI1
7     0   control
8     1   control
9         control
10    0     AOMI2
11    1     AOMI2
12    2     AOMI2
```

I want to rename all instances of '1' in the column called 'Loop' but differently for different conditions in the 'Condition' column. For the 'base' and 'control' conditions I want '1' to be renamed 'imageryQ' and for 'AOMI1' and 'AOMI2' I want '1' to become 'VI'. This is what I want the data to look like:

```
      Loop2 Condition
1         0      base
2  imageryQ      base
3                base
4         0     AOMI1
5        VI     AOMI1
6         2     AOMI1
7         0   control
8  imageryQ   control
9             control
10        0     AOMI2
11       VI     AOMI2
12        2     AOMI2
```

It would be better if this could be done based on the column contents as opposed to row numbers as I'm not sure whether the data could change. It's unlikely to change though, so if a solution using row numbers is much simpler those options would be good too!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `case_when` just like in the link you posted.

`mutate(df, Loop2 = case_when(Loop != 1 ~ Loop, Condition %in% c("base", "control") ~ "imageryQ", str_detect(Condition, "AOMI") ~ "VI"))`

Comment: @caldwellst Thank you, but this doesn't work. Running your code changes every instance of 1, 2 or NA in the Loop column instead of just 1 for the base, AOMI1 and AOMI2 conditions and NAs replace 1 and 2 in the Loop column for the control condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a simple dplyr::[case_when](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) function:

```
library(tidyverse)

Loop <- c('0','1','','0','1','2','0','1','','0','1','2')
Condition <- c('base','base','base','AOMI1','AOMI1','AOMI1','control','control',
               'control','AOMI2','AOMI2','AOMI2')

df <- data.frame(Loop, Condition)

df %>%
  mutate(Loop = case_when(
    Loop == "1" & Condition == "base" ~ "imageryQ",
    Loop == "1" & Condition == "control" ~ "imageryQ",
    Loop == "1" & Condition == "AOMI1" ~ "VI",
    Loop == "1" & Condition == "AOMI2" ~ "VI",
    TRUE ~ Loop
  ))
```

You can shorten this up by writing

```
Loop == "1" & Condition %in% c("base","contorl") ~ "imageryQ"
```